# Pegando texto dos diferentes inputs

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estou precisando pegar diferentes texto dos inputs, já tentei e da certo para alguns, abaixo uma lista dos que funcionaram.

lbl_DteHora_Reu
slc_Local_Reu
slc_Palavra_Reu
slc_QuebraGelo_Reu
slc_Louvor_Reu

HTML:

```
            <label class="item item-input widget uib_w_60 d-margins ajustes" data-uib="ionic/input" data-ver="0" ><span class="input-label">Data e Hora</span>
            <input type="datetime-local" id="lbl_DteHora_Reu">
        </label>
        <label class="item item-input item-select widget uib_w_67 d-margins" data-uib="ionic/select" data-ver="0">
            <div class="input-label">Local</div>
            <select id="slc_Local_Reu" class="slc_Reuniao">
                <option value="SO" selected="">--</option>
                <option value="OT">Outro</option>
            </select>
        </label>
        <input id="lbl_Endereco_Reu" type="text" placeholder="Digite o outro endereço">

        <label class="item item-input item-select widget uib_w_62 d-margins" data-uib="ionic/select" data-ver="0">
            <div class="input-label">Palavra</div>
            <select id="slc_Palavra_Reu" class="slc_Reuniao">
                <option value="SO" selected="">--</option>
                <option value="OT">Outro</option>
            </select>
        </label>
        <input id="lbl_Palavra_Reu" type="text" placeholder="Digite outra pessoa para palavra">

        <label class="item item-input item-select widget uib_w_63 d-margins" data-uib="ionic/select" data-ver="0">
            <div class="input-label">Quebra Gelo</div>
            <select id="slc_QuebraGelo_Reu" class="slc_Reuniao">
                <option value="SO" selected="">--</option>
                <option value="OT">Outro</option>
            </select>
        </label>
        <input id="lbl_QuebraGelo_Reu" type="text" placeholder="Digite outra pessoa para o quebra gelo">
        <label class="item item-input item-select widget uib_w_64 d-margins" data-uib="ionic/select" data-ver="0">
            <div class="input-label">Louvor</div>
            <select id="slc_Louvor_Reu" class="slc_Reuniao">
                <option value="SO" selected="">--</option>
                <option value="OT">Outro</option>
            </select>
        </label>
        <input id="lbl_Louvor_Reu" type="text" placeholder="Digite outra pessoa para o louvor">
        <label class="item item-input widget uib_w_65 d-margins ajustes_button" data-uib="ionic/textarea" data-ver="0">
            <textarea id="txt_Observacoes_Reu" placeholder="Observação" rows="10" wrap="hard"></textarea>
        </label>
```

Jquery:

```
        /* button  #btn_Salvar_Reuniao */
$(document).on("click", "#btn_Salvar_Reuniao", function(evt)
{
  var dtHora = $("#lbl_DteHora_Reu").val();
  var local = $("#slc_Local_Reu").val();
  var local_outro = $("#lbl_Endereco_Reu").val();
  var palavra = $("#slc_Palavra_Reu").val();
  var palavra_outro = $("#lbl_Palavra_Reu").val();
  var quebragelo = $("#slc_QuebraGelo_Reu").val();
  var quebragelo_outro = $("#lbl_QuebraGelo_Reu").val();
  var louvor = $("#slc_Louvor_Reu").val();
  var louvor_outro = $("#lbl_Louvor_Reu").val();
  var obs = $("textarea#txt_Observacoes_Reu").val();

  console.log(dtHora+","+local+",",+local_outro+",",+palavra+",",+palavra_outro+",",+
  quebragelo+",",+quebragelo_outro+",",+louvor+",",+louvor_outro+",",+   obs);

  if (local == "SO" || local_outro == "" || palavra == "SO" || palavra_outro == "" || quebragelo == "SO" || quebragelo_outro == "" || louvor== "SO" || louvor_outro == ""){
    alert("Não pode haver nenhum campo vazio");
  }else{
    alert("Pode cadastrar");
  }

});
```

A Minha ideia é quando clicar deixar no select `outro` ele abra um input para ser digitado, está funcionando perfeito até está parte, quando coloco um valor no select ele pega tudo certinho, porem quando deixo em outro ele não pega os dados do input.

Fiz um exemplo no fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/#run&togetherjs=hpc2TmqAnv

> O interessante é que quando eu seleciono uma das outras opções do select sem ser `outro` eu pego o valor correto e o valor do campo `input` referente ao mesmo vem `0`, porem quando seleciono outro ele informa `NaN` o mesmo problema acontece no textarea, se não tem conteúdo ele informa `0` se adiciono conteúdo ele informa `NaN`

Comment: tente desta maneira: document.getElementById("lbl_Endereco_Reu").value

Comment: continua dando o mesmo problema, ja verifiquei as ids, e estão todas corretas

Comment: pelo que entendi o seu problema é pegar o valor do campo input, sendo assim aqui funciona http://jsfiddle.net/sL5n8nt9/1/

Comment: tente isso
`var local_outro = $('#lbl_Endereco_Reu').prop('value');`

Comment: @ThiagoFriedman Ok ai está funcionando porem eu tenho opção de pegar o value dos inputs tbem

Comment: @feresjorge ao utilizar o que me sugeriu deu  o mesmo problema, a saida foi: 2015-09-07T04:52,39, 0, NaN, NaN, 1, 0, 1, 0, NaN [Pros dois primeiros `NaN` os dados inseridos foram `outro` e `asdasda`] e para o ultimo foi inserido no textarea `asd2wqada`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como reparaste também tinhas um erro de sintaxeno console.log aqui

```
 console.log(dtHora+","+local+",",+local_outro+","
                                 ^^
```

Há maneiras melhores de escrever isso e que evitam esse tipo de problemas. Assim em vêz de escrever

```
console.log(dtHora+","+local+","+local_outro+","+palavra+","+palavra_outro+","+  quebragelo+","+quebragelo_outro+","+louvor+","+louvor_outro+","+   obs);
```

podes escrever com `['a', 'b', 'c'].join('", "')` e dessa maneira separas as variáveis da string que as vai juntar. No teu caso ficaria assim:

```
console.log([dtHora, local, local_outro, palavra, palavra_outro, quebragelo, quebragelo_outro, louvor, louvor_outro, obs].join('","'));
```

Outro aspeto, que pode facilitar a leitura e estrutura de código é tratar isso de maneira mais escalável. Assim podias ter o código desta maneira:

```
// esta primeira linha/array é o unico sitio onde inseres conteúdo. 
// O resto são passos de processamento desta mesma array
var ids = ["#lbl_DteHora_Reu","#slc_Local_Reu","#lbl_Endereco_Reu","#slc_Palavra_Reu","#lbl_Palavra_Reu","#slc_QuebraGelo_Reu","#lbl_QuebraGelo_Reu","#slc_Louvor_Reu","#lbl_Louvor_Reu","textarea#txt_Observacoes_Reu"];
var elementos = ids.map($); // transformar uma array de ids em array de objetos jQuery (*nota 1)

// aqui é a mesma ideia que em cima só que transformando a array de elementos/objetos numa array com os seus valores
// a ideia de `.get()` é para o jQuery retornar uma array nativa e `join()` expliquei no inicio da resposta => para concatenar a array.
var string = elementos.map(function(){
    return $(this).val();
}).get().join('","');
console.log(string);

// O método filter remove elementos da array, fazendo-a mais pequena.
// Se no final não tiver removidos todos então há algun(s) vazios e o `length` vai dar positivo
var vazios = elementos.filter(function(){
    var value = $(this).val();
    return this.tagName.toLowerCase() == 'select' ? value == 'SO' : value == '';
}).length;

if (vazios ){
    alert("Não pode haver nenhum campo vazio");
}else{
    alert("Pode cadastrar");
}
```

Desse modo tratas os valores de forma mais programática reduzindo margem de erro.

#### Notas explicativas:

**#1** - `var elementos = ids.map($);` vai percorrer todos os elementos e para cada um fazer `elementos[x] = $(id[x]). Ou seja a função`.map(function(id, index){`passa para`$` um id de cada vez.

Comment: Muito bom, irei estudar mais sobre, se caso tiver alguma dica de vídeo aula ou livros para abranger mais estes detalhes gostaria que acrescenta-se na resposta, penso ser bom para todos. Porem se não tiver agradeço pela resposta, e que Deus te abençoe!

Answer (score 3):

O erro era algo grotesco, o problema estava no console.log

```
console.log(dtHora+","+local+",",+local_outro+",",+palavra+",",+palavra_outro+",",+
  quebragelo+",",+quebragelo_outro+",",+louvor+",",+louvor_outro+",",+   obs);
```

Eu coloquei `,` fora das `aspas`, apos tira-las funcionou sem mais nenhuma alteração.

o correto:

```
console.log(dtHora+","+local+","+local_outro+","+palavra+","+palavra_outro+","+
  quebragelo+","+quebragelo_outro+","+louvor+","+louvor_outro+","+   obs);
```